# RequireJS not loading from paths confing

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have the following main.js

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'js',
  paths: {
    "jquery": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"
  },
  shim: {
    'backbone': {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'marionette': {
      deps: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
      exports: 'Marionette'
    },
    'underscore': {
      exports: '_'
    }
  }

});
```

The code to require query:

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'marionette'], function($, Backbone, Marionette) {
```

Backbone, marionette and underscore all load correctly, but requireJS is ignoring the 'paths' config and trying to load jquery from js/jquery.js, not the CDN.

Using requires 2.1.9

Comment: Can you show us the code that makes RequireJS load jQuery? (Either the ``define`` that lists jQuery as a requirement or the ``require`` that mentions jQuery.)

Comment: I have updated as requested

Answer (score 2):

You should exclude the ".js" extension from the CDN URL, just as you would for file paths in your `baseUrl` directory:

```
paths: {
    "jquery": "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min"
  },
```